# Вылетает консольное приложение

Tags: c

У меня возник такой вопрос. Вот я написал консольное приложение на си. В codeblocks оно работает как надо, то есть ввод-вывод. Но когда приложение открывать через экзэшник (*.ехе) в папке программы, реализуется только ввод, а дальше программа просто вылетает.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c, m;
    printf("Input values for comparsion: \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); 
    m = a;
    if (b < m) {
        m = b;
    }
    if (c < m) {
        m = c;
    }
    printf("Minimum is: %d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Банальное приложение, чтобы просто разобраться с этой проблемой. Пробовал вставлять `getch()` и после `scanf`, и перед `return`.

Ноль эффекта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: "...а дальше программа просто вылетает" - что это значит? "Но когда приложение открывать через экзэшник..." - что имеется в виду под этим? Это - консольное приложение, как вы сами его назвали. Его надо запускать из консоли. Вы запускаете из консоли?

Comment: да даже через консоль в vs code вылетает. вот, допустим, запускаю отладку в vs code, ввожу данные, нажимаю энтер, и программа вылетает

Comment: Все там работает, скорее всего вы просто вводите в неправильном формате. Разделяйте числа пробелами, а не запятыми.

Comment: я так и делаю:) у меня ж еще немного мозгов-то осталось:)

Comment: "Вылетает" - это не описание проблемы. Вам явно стоит познакомиться с отладчиком. Если программа нормально доходит до `return 0`, то значит ничего не вылетает, а если нет - тогда следует написать на какой конкретной строке что происходит.

Comment: `Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

в общем. вот что пишет отладчик

Comment: В этом нет ничего страшного, просто не для всех системных библиотек отладчик находит отладочные символы.

Comment: Вы уверены, что оно именно вылетает, а не отрабатывает и закрывается? Попробуйте использовать getchar вместо getch. Как вариант можно просто ввести код в бесконечный цикл, из которого можно будет вызодить по нажатию какой-либо клавиши